# How to move view for value in UISlider in Swift?

Tags: swift, transition, uislider

I have a UISlider with 50 values. How to move different UIView, when value in slider changes?

I've tried this:

```
if oldValue < Int(sender.value) {
        viewToMove.center.y = viewToMove.center.y - heightOfDay
        print(viewToMove.center.y)
        oldValue = Int(sender.value)
         print(oldValue)
    } else if oldValue > Int(sender.value) {
        viewToMove.center.y = viewToMove.center.y + heightOfDay
        print(viewToMove.center.y)
        oldValue = Int(sender.value)
        print(oldValue)
    }
```

Slider's value changing but viewToMove.center.y isn't.

Comment: test view.layoutIfNeeded() after your changes

Comment: How the viewToMove is added and layouted to the view hierarchy?
If there is used auto layout, then you need to update the constant of the NSLayoutConstraint which holds the centerY positon of the viewToMove

Comment: @Samps, Yes, thank you, this solved my problem. If you'll post this as answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probably is the `viewToMove` layout added with auto layout.
If so, then you need to update the constant of the NSLayoutConstraint which holds the `centerY` position of the `viewToMove`